# "Aún" vs. "todavía", what's the difference?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, sinónimos

Somebody just asked me to correct something, and I found that I changed one of their instances of *todavía* to *aún*. I didn't do this because *todavía* wouldn't have worked in the sentence, but rather because I just felt *aún* flowed better.

The original sentence was:

> *En la Filipinas, ¿las escuelas todavían enseñar el sujeto de español como una segunda idioma?*

I corrected it to:

> *¿En las Filipinas, enseñan aún las escuelas la materia de español como idioma extranjero?*

**Please don't get distracted by the translation.** I'm just wondering if my choice of *aún* was correct here, and if so, what is the difference between it and *todavía*? I seem to have picked some understanding along the way that led me to do that, but I want to confirm it more concretely or know if my suspicion was baseless and this is something I made up.

The thread "*[aún,todavía](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=195772)*" on Word Reference seems to confirm what I thought: basically, that one should use what sounds better, that there are regional differences, and that *aún* is more literary.

Comment: native spanish speaker here, they are 100% interchangeable for me in that phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Todavía** usually sounds better in informal situations. They are almost always interchangeable, but there are a few exceptions:

> Aún also means "hasta": 
>   "Fué demasiada cerveza, aún para mí"
>
> Aún as a conjuntion ("ni"):
>   "No tomaría más, aún cuando me lo pidieras"
>   "No quiso tomar, aún habiéndoselo pedido"

---

Another situation where they are not interchangeable is (as always) poetry:

> "Hoy es siempre todavía"
>   Antonio Machado

Comment: I think that in your two examples: "No tomaría más, aún cuando me lo pidieras" and "No quiso tomar, aún habiéndoselo pedido", it should be "aun" (no accent mark) and not "aún", since the meaning is that of "incluso". As the RAE says, "aún" only has accent mark when it can be replaced by "todavía".

Comment: @Gonazalo I guess you are right, but I share my concerns with (at least) this pour soul :http://trampalabras.blogspot.com/2010/12/aun-todavia-lleva-acento.html?showComment=1301452935411#c1243519444486260359

Comment: This answer best covers what I was looking for, since I know the definitions already.

Comment: I agree with @GonzaloMedina. This answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

The difference resides in that **aú(u)n** has two possible meanings. And that **todavía** has one when in comparison with it.

Meaning of todavía according to RAE:

> [todavía.](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=todav%C3%ADa)
>
> (De toda y vía).
>
> 1. adv. t. Hasta un momento determinado desde tiempo anterior. Está durmiendo todavía.
> 2. adv. t. ant. siempre (‖ en todo tiempo).
> 3. adv. m. Con todo eso, no obstante, sin embargo. Es muy ingrato, pero todavía quiero yo hacerle bien.
> 4. adv. m. U. con sentido concesivo corrigiendo una frase anterior. ¿Para qué ahorras?; todavía si tuvieras hijos estaría justificado.
> 5. adv. m. Denota encarecimiento o ponderación. Juan es todavía más aplicado que su hermano.

Aún means almost the same. The difference is the accent, that can change its overall meaning. **Todavía** and **aún** are sometimes called perfect synonims because they are claimed to be interchangeable. As Belisarius said and posted the rules, so I won't repost the rules here.

Now the meaning of **Aú(u)n** by RAE:

> [aun](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=todav%C3%ADa).
>
> (Del lat. adhuc).
>
> 1. adv. t. todavía (‖ hasta un momento determinado).
> 2. adv. m. todavía (‖ no obstante, sin embargo).
> 3. adv. m. todavía (‖ en sentido concesivo).
> 4. adv. m. todavía (‖ en sentido de encarecimiento o ponderación).
> 5. adv. m. Denota a veces idea de encarecimiento en sentido afirmativo o negativo.
>
> ORTOGR. Escr. con acento cuando pueda sustituirse por todavía. Aún
>   ('todavía') está enfermo. En los demás casos, se escribirá sin tilde.
>   Te daré 100 duros, y aun ('hasta') 200, si los necesitas. No tengo yo
>   tanto, ni aun ('ni siquiera') la mitad.

As RAE says it is almost always interchangeable, but when it isn't aun has no accent. What does this mean? It means that aun is being used as **even**. To be concrete you write **aun** when you can substitute it by **incluso** this inherently means that it can't be changeable with **todavía**.

These are some examples to illustrate this point:

> El Gobierno francés está persuadido de la “ilegalidad” de la operación
>   [...], pero aun así dará asistencia consular y jurídica a los 16
>   detenidos
>
> Pero ningún hombre es respetable, ni aun los santos, ni aun los locos,
>   ni aun los niños que juegan con piedras junto a los pozos
>
> Te puedo prestar 100 euros, aun 200; contal de que me los devuelvas.

[Source for aun and aún.](http://blog.lengua-e.com/2007/aun-con-tilde-y-aun-sin-tilde/)